# Primefaces: p:Wizard not working properly inside p:outputpanel

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My requirement is to display a wizard depending upon the product selected by User (using a drop down). So i using a p:wizard component containing few steps inside p:outpanel (with autoupdate true). When this is initially rendered everything looks fine i.e. all the tabs and navigation buttons are displayed properly.
But upon clicking on next button, the Navigation buttons and the header Tabs are disappearing.
PFB the sample code and screenshot that i created to verify this bug.

```
 <p:panel style="height: 100px;width:500px">
      <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
         <p:wizard>
            <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
                  Sample Tab 1
                  </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab 2">
                  Sample Tab 2</p:tab>
            <p:tab id="tab3" title="Tab 3">
                  Sample Tab 3</p:tab>
         </p:wizard>
      </p:outputPanel>
      </p:panel>
```

[image]

[image]

---

Manual update is not refreshing the Data inside the Data Table. I have a pretty messed up requirement.
I have a form within which i have a datatable and two command buttons namely **delete** and **update details**.
On clicking delete, the selected record must get deleted from the datatable (DB is updating but not the UI). And on clicking "update Details", a wizard must be displayed under the data table which contains details regarding the selected record. User should be able to select different record from the data table and the wizard must get updated with the proper data.

Now i am facing multiple problems,

1. if i make delete button to be ajax, then the datatable is not updating (without using outputpanel or updating the complete form).
2. If i use the outputpanel then, the UI is getting messed up on filtering or sorting (due to viewstate not restored).
3. If i create separate forms for datatable and the wizard, and try updating the wizard data from "update details" button. Then also
   the wizard data is not getting updated.
4. If i use the outputpanel then, the WIzard UI is getting messed up on clicking next (due to viewstate not restored).

**PFB the dummy code for the scenario:**

```
<h:form id="form1">
  <p:outputpanel id="panel1">
       <p:datatable value="#{someBeanMethod}" var="someData">
       //Some data Table columns
       <f:facet name="footer">
                  <p:commandbutton id="button1" value="delete" 
                             actionListner="#{deletFuntion}" update="@(form1:panel1)"/>
                 <p:commandbutton id="button2" value="viewDetails" 
                             actionListner="#{fetchViewMethod}" update="@(form1:panel2)"/>
       </f:facet>
       </p:datatable>
   </p:outputpanel>

   <p:outputpanel id="panel2">
      <p:wizard id="wizard1" rendered = "#{someFlag}">
                //Some Functionality
       </p:wizard>
   </p:outputpanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Why do you need an `p:outputPanel`? The `p:wizard` automatically render some kind of panel and updates it after processing the `flowListener`. Please show the java code which processes the `flowListener` action.

Comment: There are no special flowlistner. i am using the default one. Problem is not with the wizard data getting updated when next is clicked.
I've used the outputpanel because the complete wizard needs to be update dynamically.

Comment: 1. Use `action="#{..}"` instead of `actionListener`.
2. The `p:dataTable` has a `selection="single"` attribute, use it. So the backing bean (call it `myBean`) accessed by the two buttons know which record should be processed. That way the two buttons *can* be made ajax buttons (like they are now).
3. The `panel2` needs to fetch the selected record from `myBean` and show details about the record.
4. `button1` only needs to update the `p:dataTable`, `button2` only panel2` - there should be no "viewstate not restored" problem".

Comment: Thanks for reply @Manuel, but the suggestions wont work (have already tried) for my case, 
"action" asks for navigation, and i dont want navigation (even not to the same page) as this part is present inside a "Tab view".
The selection mode is already single, and the selections are proper.

**panel2** button is refreshing the table data at backend but it is not getting updated at UI, just to tackle the UI refresh problem i went for the p:outputpanel, and hell broke loose